# Fade In and out prefab through minutes instead of seconds?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a bird script that hovers over the player. I have everything set in float seconds but I want that my `IEnumerator FadeIn()` function use 2 minutes instead. This will help because I want players to have some time to shoot down the bird without having the issue of the game automatically resetting in a matter of seconds.The point of my game is that if players take too long the bird will attack them causing a reset window to appear. **What I did was multiply 60 but that didn't seem to work.** I also notice I have to press "S" twice for fading out to work sometimes **will look into debugging for that**

```
public float waitTime = 0.0f;
public float fadeTime = 1.0f;
public float betweenFadesTime = 1.0f;

// Flag to determine whether or not the player may respond.
public bool canRespond = false;

// Flag to determine if the player has responded within the wait time.
public bool hasResponded = false;

public GameObject enemy;

void Start()
{ 
    StartCoroutine(EnemyFadeIn(fadeTime, betweenFadesTime, waitTime)); 
}

void Update() {
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) && (canRespond))
    { hasResponded = true; }
}

IEnumerator EnemyFadeIn(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
    Debug.Log("An Enemy Is Fading In");
    // Simulating Fade In Time.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToFade);
    Debug.Log("An Enemy Has Appeared");
    yield return ListenForInput(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait * 60f);
}

IEnumerator EnemyFadeOut(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
    Debug.Log("An Enemy Is Fading Away");
    // Simulating Fade Out Time.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToFade);
    Debug.Log("An Enemy Has Departed");
    // Simulating Time Between Fades.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenFades);

    yield return EnemyFadeIn(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
}

// Responsible for reacting to the 'S' key input.
IEnumerator ListenForInput(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
    canRespond = true;
    Debug.Log("Press the 'S' Key to Destroy the Enemy!");
    float startTime = Time.time;

    // Check every 0.25 seconds to see if the S key was pressed.
    while (Time.time < (startTime + timeToWait)) {
        if (hasResponded) {
            Debug.Log("The 'S' Key was Pressed!");
            hasResponded = false;
            canRespond = false;
            yield return EnemyFadeOut(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
    }
```

Comment: Ok you got 2 seemingly unrelated issues here. Start with a smaller one - why do you have to press 'S' twice? So put a bullet point at `hasResponded = true;` in `Update` function and debug. If you don't know how to debug you MUST learn it because programming essentially about pro debugging than pro coding, and in which case watch this (or any other) video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFFexymk3FY

Comment: Thats the thing theirs a glitch where once I press 's' for the first time my fade out doesnt react until I press a second time. So im asking for a logical explination for that. Will look into debugging.

Comment: Your first instinct, when you have a problem, shouldn't be stack overflow, it should be trying to figure out the problem on your own. Debugging is an essential skill that you *need* to learn.

Comment: I'm sure your an admin so I won't be quite disrespectful. After all the comments _are_ for more clarification rather than belittling. I agree that StackOverFlow _shouldn't_ be my first option. I realized debugging was the way to go and have found another way to make this work. Either by `While` statements within my `Ienumerator` or through simple `SetActive`.